# How can I update the first array's object if second array contains same object with different values except a primary value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**This is my first array**

```
[{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084622977,"s":"ETHBTC","p":"-0.00260600","P":"-4.029","w":"0.06279622",
  "x":"0.06465200","c":"0.06207700","Q":"0.10800000","b":"0.06207900","B":"0.58000000","a":"0.06209300",
  "A":"0.59600000","o":"0.06468300","h":"0.06501900","l":"0.06132100","v":"129608.83100000",
  "q":"8138.94504722","O":1531998222974,"C":1532084622974,"F":73853949,"L":74063645,"n":209697},
{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084702133,"s":"SUBBTC","p":"-0.00000220","P":"-5.952","w":"0.00003644",
  "x":"0.00003697","c":"0.00003476","Q":"160.00000000","b":"0.00003475","B":"1395.00000000","a":"0.00003491",
  "A":"2985.00000000","o":"0.00003696","h":"0.00003924","l":"0.00003336","v":"7748269.00000000",
  "q":"282.36375628","O":1531998302130,"C":1532084702130,"F":4037874,"L":4054769,"n":16896},
{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084748775,"s":"BCCBTC","p":"-0.00526500","P":"-4.705","w":"0.10905664",
  "x":"0.11204400","c":"0.10664900","Q":"0.08300000","b":"0.10658300","B":"8.52800000","a":"0.10677900",
  "A":"0.77900000","o":"0.11191400","h":"0.11326700","l":"0.10472000","v":"21080.58100000",
  "q":"2298.97740586","O":1531998348774,"C":1532084748774,"F":10914609,"L":10941459,"n":26851},
{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084748660,"s":"MCOBTC","p":"-0.00011400","P":"-10.899","w":"0.00098345",
  "x":"0.00104600","c":"0.00093200","Q":"24.02000000","b":"0.00093000","B":"171.33000000","a":"0.00093200"
, "A":"168.75000000","o":"0.00104600","h":"0.00105200","l":"0.00092500","v":"99507.04000000",
  "q":"97.86033310","O":1531998348658,"C":1532084748658,"F":4480923,"L":4485667,"n":4745}]
```

**And this is my second array**

```
[{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084661691,"s":"ETHBTC","p":"-0.00257400","P":"-3.980","w":"0.06279576",
  "x":"0.06467300","c":"0.06209900","Q":"0.85000000","b":"0.06207500","B":"2.03000000","a":"0.06209900",
    "A":"9.46000000","o":"0.06467300","h":"0.06501900","l":"0.06132100","v":"129621.22800000",
  "q":"8139.66334220","O":1531998261688,"C":1532084661688,"F":73854007,"L":74063690,"n":209684},
 {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084702133,"s":"SUBBTC","p":"-0.00000220","P":"-5.952","w":"0.00003644",
  "x":"0.00003697","c":"0.00003476","Q":"160.00000000","b":"0.00003475","B":"1395.00000000","a":"0.00003491",
  "A":"2985.00000000","o":"0.00003696","h":"0.00003924","l":"0.00003336","v":"7748269.00000000",
  "q":"243.12375628","O":1531998302130,"C":1532084702130,"F":4037874,"L":4054769,"n":16896}]
```

I want to loop through my second array. There are 2 objects in it. Please note that second array  will always be a subset of the first array. In my second array, my first object has a value of s ETHBTC.

I want to update the value of `c` and `q` from that object to the value of `c` and `q` in my first array's object such that the value of s is `ETHBTC`. Basically, I want to update the values of my first object.

Comment: `for-loop` `-->` `array1[i].c = arra2[i].c`

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: You can definitely do this independently of jQuery. Plain JavaScript will do.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you are going to do is not going to scale well. What you need to do is keep object references. By that way, whenever you edit the object in first array, that will be reflected in second array since both are referring to the same object.

Whenever you want to have a separate/detached copy of an object, use spread operator as below.

```js
let obj1 = {
  "e": "value1"
}
let obj2 = {
  "e": "value2"
}
let obj3 = {
  "e": "value3"
}

let arr = [obj1, obj2, obj3];

let arr2 = [obj1, obj2];

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);

obj1.e = "Changed the value";
arr[1].e = "Changed the value using array ref";

console.log("After changing");
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);

//whenever you want to detatch from parent reference use spread oeprator
let obj1Clone = { ...obj1
};

obj1Clone.e = "Changed Again, but a copy";

console.log("After changing again!");
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(obj1Clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var arrA=[{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084622977,"s":"ETHBTC","p":"-0.00260600","P":"-4.029","w":"0.06279622",
   "x":"0.06465200","c":"0.06207700","Q":"0.10800000","b":"0.06207900","B":"0.58000000","a":"0.06209300",
   "A":"0.59600000","o":"0.06468300","h":"0.06501900","l":"0.06132100","v":"129608.83100000",
   "q":"8138.94504722","O":1531998222974,"C":1532084622974,"F":73853949,"L":74063645,"n":209697},
 {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084702133,"s":"SUBBTC","p":"-0.00000220","P":"-5.952","w":"0.00003644",
   "x":"0.00003697","c":"0.00003476","Q":"160.00000000","b":"0.00003475","B":"1395.00000000","a":"0.00003491",
   "A":"2985.00000000","o":"0.00003696","h":"0.00003924","l":"0.00003336","v":"7748269.00000000",
   "q":"282.36375628","O":1531998302130,"C":1532084702130,"F":4037874,"L":4054769,"n":16896},
 {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084748775,"s":"BCCBTC","p":"-0.00526500","P":"-4.705","w":"0.10905664",
   "x":"0.11204400","c":"0.10664900","Q":"0.08300000","b":"0.10658300","B":"8.52800000","a":"0.10677900",
   "A":"0.77900000","o":"0.11191400","h":"0.11326700","l":"0.10472000","v":"21080.58100000",
   "q":"2298.97740586","O":1531998348774,"C":1532084748774,"F":10914609,"L":10941459,"n":26851},
 {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084748660,"s":"MCOBTC","p":"-0.00011400","P":"-10.899","w":"0.00098345",
   "x":"0.00104600","c":"0.00093200","Q":"24.02000000","b":"0.00093000","B":"171.33000000","a":"0.00093200"
 , "A":"168.75000000","o":"0.00104600","h":"0.00105200","l":"0.00092500","v":"99507.04000000",
   "q":"97.86033310","O":1531998348658,"C":1532084748658,"F":4480923,"L":4485667,"n":4745}];

var arrB=[{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084661691,"s":"ETHBTC","p":"-0.00257400","P":"-3.980","w":"0.06279576",
   "x":"0.06467300","c":"0.06209900","Q":"0.85000000","b":"0.06207500","B":"2.03000000","a":"0.06209900",
   "A":"9.46000000","o":"0.06467300","h":"0.06501900","l":"0.06132100","v":"129621.22800000",
   "q":"8139.66334220","O":1531998261688,"C":1532084661688,"F":73854007,"L":74063690,"n":209684},
  {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1532084702133,"s":"SUBBTC","p":"-0.00000220","P":"-5.952","w":"0.00003644",
   "x":"0.00003697","c":"0.00003476","Q":"160.00000000","b":"0.00003475","B":"1395.00000000","a":"0.00003491",
   "A":"2985.00000000","o":"0.00003696","h":"0.00003924","l":"0.00003336","v":"7748269.00000000",
   "q":"243.12375628","O":1531998302130,"C":1532084702130,"F":4037874,"L":4054769,"n":16896}];
   
function check(A){console.log(A.s,A.c,A.q);}
console.log('before:')
arrA.forEach(check);

// this is the place where the magic happens:
arrB.forEach(B=>arrA.forEach(A=>{if (A.s==B.s){A.c=B.c;A.q=B.q}}));

console.log('after:')
arrA.forEach(check);
```